# Nested absolute positioning breaks inline-block child elements

Tags: css, position, css-position, absolute

I am having difficulties sustaining my `display: inline-block` on `li` elements when they're deeply nested in numerous parent containers with varying `position: absolute|relative`, I am wondering if there is a set of rules that govern this?

In a sandboxed environment this works fine: [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j1d1wu1o/).

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.body {
  position: absolute;
}
.one {
  position: absolute;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.three {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
.four {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.agent-dropdown {
  position: asbolute;
}
.box {
  background: grey;
  padding: 8px;
}
.box-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="agent-dropdown">
  <div class="box-container">
    <div class="box">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
          </a>
        </li><li>
        <a>
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
        </a>
        </li><li>
        <a>
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when nested to the level that it is on the live website, the `li` elements lose their formation, it seems to break after the 3rd `position: absolute`. [JS Fiddle (Broken)](https://jsfiddle.net/xugafvyx/1/)

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
}
.body {
  position: absolute;
}
.one {
  position: absolute;
}
.two {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.three {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
}
.four {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.agent-dropdown {
  position: asbolute;
}
.box {
  background: grey;
  padding: 8px;
}
.box-container {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="one">
    <div class="two">
      <div class="three">
        <div class="four">
          <div class="agent-dropdown">
            <div class="box-container">
              <div class="box">
                <ul>
                  <li>
                    <a>
                      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
                    </a>
                  </li><li>
                  <a>
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
                  </a>
                  </li><li>
                  <a>
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
                  </a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am unable to use fixed widths or heights anywhere.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 2):

In your absolutely positioned elements, all `left`, `margin-left`, `width`, `margin-right` and `right` are set to `auto`.

Therefore, according to [10.3.7 Absolutely positioned, non-replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width),

> the width is shrink-to-fit

The algorithm to calculate the shrink-to-fit width is

> min(max(preferred minimum width, available width), preferred width).

Therefore,

- `.body` is absolutely positioned and its content is out of flow. So the preferred width is `0`. So the shrink-to-fit width is `0`.
- The same applies to `.one`.
- `.two` is also absolutely positioned, but its content is not out of flow. The shrink to fit width is the minimal width needed when placing the images in different lines, because

  - The preferred minimum width is the minimal width needed when placing the images in different lines.
  - The preferred width is the width needed when placing the images in the same line.
  - The available width is 0.

  ```
  0 = available width < preferred minimum width < preferred width
  ```

If you don't want that behavior, you can

- Increase the available width, so that

  ```
  preferred minimum width < preferred width < available width
  ```

  For example,

  ```css
  .body, .one {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
  }
  .body, .one {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
  }
  .two {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  .three {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .four {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .agent-dropdown {
    position: asbolute;
  }
  .box {
    background: grey;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  .box-container {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="body">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
          <div class="four">
            <div class="agent-dropdown">
              <div class="box-container">
                <div class="box">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
                      </a>
                    </li><li>
                    <a>
                      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpgt" />
                    </a>
                    </li><li>
                    <a>
                      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

  - Increase the preferred minimum width, so that

  ```
  preferred minimum width = preferred width
  ```

  This can be achieved preventing line breaks:

  ```css
  .two {
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  li {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
  }
  .body, .one {
    position: absolute;
  }
  .two {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
  .three {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
  }
  .four {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
  }
  .agent-dropdown {
    position: asbolute;
  }
  .box {
    background: grey;
    padding: 8px;
  }
  .box-container {
    border: 1px solid red;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="body">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="two">
        <div class="three">
          <div class="four">
            <div class="agent-dropdown">
              <div class="box-container">
                <div class="box">
                  <ul>
                    <li>
                      <a>
                        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
                      </a>
                    </li><li>
                    <a>
                      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpgt" />
                    </a>
                    </li><li>
                    <a>
                      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/fhgTc.jpg" />
                    </a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: Thank you for this, appreciate the information and explanation. Helped a lot!